# Docker has to build spring app and then run it

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm not able to make Docker build my application and then run it. I have an excercise where I cannot pre-build the application and then run it, Docker has to do the building.

```
Here's my Dockerfile:
FROM maven:3.5.3-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean install

COPY ./target/worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

after doing 
    `docker build -t worker .`

I get an error:

```
[INFO] Installing /usr/src/target/worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /root/.m2/repository/com/heiko/worker/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /usr/src/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/com/heiko/worker/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 41.059 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-27T16:04:10Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Removing intermediate container d8d33baa7558
 ---> 3509c06f8736
Step 5/7 : COPY ./target/worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder701090107/target/worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar something that `mvn clean install` builds?    `COPY` copies files from the docker host to the docker container (like you use in `COPY . .`, copy the target directory of the docker build to the `WORKDIR`, to copy your code into the container).

If you want to move around files *within* the container, you should use

```
RUN cp ./target/worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This will create 2 copies of the file in the docker container, one at target/worker...jar and one at ./worker...jar.  If you want only one copy, you'd have to use `mv` (move) instead and move the file *in the same layer that created it*, otherwise the layering system of docker will preserve the old location anyway.  I think you might be able to achieve it with something like:

RUN mvn clean install && mv ./target/worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar worker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

hint for further optimization of image size & security: you can keep the final image even smaller by using a multi-stage build (https://aboullaite.me/multi-stage-docker-java/ seems to be a good maven explanation.)